# Fluid style content "Menu of selected pages" subtitle // title

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-9.x, fluid-styled-content

TYPO3 v. 9.5.15

fluid_style_content and menu_pages

I'm using the TYPO3 Menu element "Pages - Menu of selected pages". As default Title is used. How can I change this so Subtitle is used ? Like this:  subtitle // title

Before I could do something like this:
tt_content.menu.20.default.1.ACT.stdWrap.field = subtitle // title

Comment: I have solved it temp. like this:
\fluid_styled_content\Resources\Private\Templates\MenuPages.html

And had inserted an condition. 

<f:if condition="{page.data.subtitle}">
 <f:then>
  <span>{page.data.subtitle}</span>
 </f:then>
 <f:else>
  <span>{page.title}</span>
 </f:else>
</f:if>

Comment: that is not temporary but the final solution - if you use the FLUID logic with replacing single template files and configuring your folders with higher priority. here: `lib.contentElement.templatelRootPaths.10 = path to your template copy` (NEVER!!! change original files from core or extensions)

Comment: That's right. Never change original files. I did move templates files from sysext folder. 
@BerndWilkeπφ
Can you move the rte_ckeditor from sysext folder? Do you make a copy of the ext or? Do you know that. Problem is when you extend the editor I think you have to do it in sysext folder and that's not the right way

Comment: what???? don't ask unrelated questions in comments but open a new question.